# Angular.js pass data from async service to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service like

```
app.factory('geolocation', function ($rootScope, cordovaReady) {
    return {
        getCurrentPosition: cordovaReady(function (onSuccess, onError, options) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function () {
                var that = this,
                    args = arguments;

                if (onSuccess) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        onSuccess.apply(that, args);
                    });
                }
            }, function () {
                var that = this,
                    args = arguments;
                if (onError) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        onError.apply(that, args);
                    });
                }
            }, options);
        }),
        getCurrentCity: function (onSuccess, onError) {
            this.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode(options,function (results, status) {
                    var city = address_component.long_name;
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And I want to do from a controller something like

```
function MainCtrl($scope, geolocation) {
   geolocation.getCurrentCity(function(city){
       $scope.city = city;
   });
};
```

The getCurrentPosition works fine and the city is determined too, however I don't know how to access the city in controller.

**What happens?** When getCurrentCity is called, it calles getCurrentPosition to determine the gps coords. This coords are passed as arguments to the onSuccess method right? So this is quite the same I want to do in the getCurrentCity method, but I don't know how. Ones the async geocoder retrieved the city, I want to apply the new data to the onSuccess method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are dealing with callbacks and asynchronous request. So you should use [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q) service. Just inject it in your service with $rootScope and cordovaReady dependency. 
And add the promises to your function like this

```
getCurrentCity: function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); 
    this.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode(options,function (results, status) {
        var city = address_component.long_name;
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
          deferred.resolve(city);
        });
      });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

And in your controller, do the following to handle the promise.

```
function MainCtrl($scope, geolocation) {
   geolocation.getCurrentCity().then(function(result) {  //result === city
     $scope.city = result;
     //do whatever you want. This will be executed once city value is available
   });     
};
```

Comment: Fixed my problem, I had a filter that was causing the loop.

Comment: The first approach in the above controller implementation of setting a $scope property to a promise does not work in Angular 1.3 any more. Promises are not unwrapped any more, so you have to use the second approach (setting the $scope property in the then handler)

Comment: @jbandi: You seem to suggest that something has changed. I didn't get what's the exact change. Do you mind clarifying it for me? I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: The code snipped above contains the line `$scope.city = geolocation.getCurrentCity();`. This line assigns a promise directly to the scope and relies on Angular to "unwrapp" this promise, this means that wehn the promise is resolved, Angular will update $scope.city to the value that was the result of the promise.
This feature of Angular of "unwrapping" promises on the $scope is no longer present in Angular 1.3 and above (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

Comment: You can read more about the reasons for removing the "promise unwrapping" feature here:
http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2013/12/05/angular-promises-unwrapping/ and here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577

Comment: @jbandi I have edited the code to reflect the current angular practise. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
function MainCtrl($scope, geolocation) {
   $scope.city = null;
   geolocation.getCurrentCity(function(city){
       $scope.city = city;
       if(!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$digest($scope);
        }
   });
};
```

Sometimes, the watcher is not always called when instanciating the controller, by forcing a digest event, if the scope is not in phase, you can go to where you want to go, I believe.
Let me know if I didn't understand your question.

Oh and I don't know if i read the code properrly but it seems that you're not calling the onSuccess callback in your function:
replace  your getCurrentCity function by this:

```
getCurrentCity: function (onSuccess, onError) {
        this.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode(options,function (results, status) {
                var city = address_component.long_name;
                if(typeof onSuccess === 'function') {
                     onSuccess(city);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just call your onSuccess method in the service instead of handling the result there.

```
getCurrentCity: function (onSuccess, onError) {
    this.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode(options, onSuccess);
    });
}
```

And in your controller, parse the results and assign the city:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, geolocation) {
   geolocation.getCurrentCity(function(results, status){
       // Parse results for the city - not sure what that object looks like
       $scope.city = results.city;
   });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the presented solution won't work completely anymore, since newer Angular versions (>1.2!?) do no longer unwrap $q promises automatically.

Thus:

```
$scope.city = geolocation.getCurrentCity();
```

will always be a promise. So you will always have to use:

```
geolocation.getCurrentCity().then(function(city) {
    $scope.city = city;
}
```