# How to access data outside of 'then'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a piece of code that I only seem to be able to access inside of `then`. I would like to get access to it outside so that I can use it in other places.

```
$scope.model = {'first_name':'','last_name':'','email':'',};
djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data){
    $scope.model = data;
    console.log($scope.model); //this prints the data
});

console.log($scope.model); //this prints empty data
```

The `profile` code is like this:

```
    'profile': function(){
        return this.request({
            'method': "GET",
            'url': "/user/"
        });
    }
```

Comment: If that was possible, then `djangoAuth.profile()` could simply return the result directly and you wouldn't have to provide a callback. The fact that you have to provide a callback tells you that the process is most likely **asynchronous**.

Comment: My intent was not to ask why it not working but how to do it in AngularJS. I understand what async means. I found my answer in a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684153/angular-js-pass-data-from-async-service-to-scope

Comment: Next time, ask exactly what you want to know. "How to access the data outside of then" is very far from "how to pass data from async service to scope".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `then` is async, even if the promise has already resolved. Angular waits until a timer-tick before it calls promise callbacks.

You can do a scope-digest to force it to evaluate immediately, but that has performance implications.