# Showing content from an Array inside infowindow on marker click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow, geocode, google-geocoding-api

i got an api endpoint that returns an array of addresses and some price information for the addresses but it doesn't return lat/lang, so i am using geocode to show the marker for the addresses on the map and showing infowindow on each marker click. Now i want the content of infowindow to be the price for the address which is in the array returned from endpoint. hope its clear so far. Now the problem is everytime i click marker, infowindow only shows last(same) price from array on each infowindow but not the price related to that address. please see my code below (or check in fiddlejs = > https://jsfiddle.net/puLxak1k/7/). It could be i am trying to call sync in asyn callback, so i tried using $q.promise and resolve on initial api call and tried calling geocode.geocoder inside .then, but no luck yet..

```
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    function initialize() {
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
    var someArray = [{price: 10, address: 'cv64ad'}, {price: 20, address: 'cv59bp'}]
    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
      var home = someArray[i]
      console.log(home.address)

      geocoder.geocode({'address': home.address}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(12);
          for (var i in results) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(results[i].geometry.location.A, results[i].geometry.location.F),
              map: map
            })
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', someCallback(home))
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            function someCallback(home) {
              return function (e) {
                if (infowindow != null) {
                  infowindow.close();
                }
                infowindow.setContent('<div class="infoheading">' + home.price + '</div>');
                infowindow.open(map, this);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jvxppeap/2/

The trick is: make an array that holds the marker objects.
Then, inside addListener(marker, 'click' ...   you check which of the markers has been clicked upon; look at "indexOf" in my code.
With that index, you can read the right item of someArray, and you can add any information you want there.

```
var markers = [];
var map;
var infowindow;
function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var someArray = [{price: 10, address: 'cv64ad'}, {price: 20, address: 'cv59bp'}];

  for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    var home = someArray[i];
    console.log(home.address);

    geocoder.geocode({'address': home.address}, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(12);
        for (var i in results) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(results[i].geometry.location.A, results[i].geometry.location.F),
            map: map
          });
          // push the marker on the markers array
          markers.push(marker);
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (home) {
              if (infowindow != null) {
                infowindow.close();
              }
              // now, we want to know which of the markers we're talking about
              var index = markers.indexOf(this);
              infowindow.setContent('<div class="infoheading">' + someArray[index].price + '</div>');
              infowindow.open(map, this);
          });
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel, it helped and solved....i was more leaning towards http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684153/angular-js-pass-data-from-async-service-to-scope

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for positing the full code and explaining functions in the comments